Multiple Formulas in 1 cell
Not sure how to explain what I am trying to accomplish but here it goes.

I have to calculate how many days that projects are open in our system AND if the project is closed to indicate that instead.
My goal is to have the cells in Column P calculate the # of days from the date of creation (Column K) to today's date (Column L) giving me the total days the project has been open for BUT if the value of the cell in Column M states "True" then instead of it calculating a number of days, I need it to simply state "N/A" (rather than give me an amount of days.)
In the Days open cell I have it calculate this by using this formula:
=IF(M2="TRUE","N/A",IF(ISTEXT(K2),"",TODAY()-K2))

Is this possible?
This apparently was the formula used in another sheet that accomplished the same thing, but it is not working in the new sheet I have create. I feel I am missing something

The True check should not be in quotes. If it is, the if statement will try to compare the string "True" instead of the Boolean value.
